# Check if FileSize is over 10GB

Tags: batch, batch-file

I want to check the size of a file und figure out if it's under or over 10 GB. This runs propably in the 32 bit variable size.

Is there any trick or a smart way to bypass this?

At the moment I am using this code:

```
SET maxbytesize=10707652095
.
.
.
FOR %%F IN ("%%~fl") DO SET size=%%~zF

IF !size! LSS !maxbytesize! (
    echo smaller 10GB
) ELSE (
    echo bigger 10GB
)
```

This code runs in the 2GB limit. All files with more than 2GB will echo "bigger 10GB". This works only with files unter 2GB.

Does anybody has an idea how to fix it?

Greetings

//Edit: maxbytesize

Comment: Can you `echo` the file size & show that it is less than 10GB , when it will show that it is more than 10 GB ? Can you check the file size in Windows Explorer ?

Comment: echo 15283191623 (14,2 GB (15.283.191.623 Bytes) explorer) => bigger 10GB

echo 4587794013 (4,27 GB (4.587.794.013 Bytes) explorer) => bigger 10GB

echo 1172228422 (1,09 GB (1.172.228.422 Bytes) explorer) => smaller 10GB

Comment: nope, 4GB is less than 10 GB but it tells its bigger. it is only working with files less than 2GB. i think it is the 32 bit problem or so?

@reddy lutonadio i found a way in powershell, but my batch scrip is huge and i dont want to migrate it now, if there is a smart and easy way to get it working

Comment: I have added a Solution, Hope it works in your case. Essentially, we are converting the large number to small number by converting to MB !

Comment: +1 for Correct Problem in 32Bit !! I will confirm this Issue in my answer shortly !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a Solution which will work in this Situation.

**STRING OPERATION :**

SET /A sizeMB=%size:~-0,-6%
SET /A maxbytesizeMB=%maxbytesize:~-0,-6%

This is converting the larger numbers to smaller numbers by leaving out 6 Digits on the right.
It makes it almost Equivalent to MegaBytes.

Now in your Batch Script, you will compare smaller numbers, which will work in 32bit Cases too.

**Here is the Exact Issue :**

**Execute** `SET /A sizeMB=4587794013/1048576`
**Output** `Invalid number.  Numbers are limited to 32-bits of precision.`

**Execute** `if 111111111 LSS 222222222 ( echo 1234 ) else ( echo 5678 )`
**Output** `1234`

**Execute** `if 1111111111 LSS 2222222222 ( echo 1234 ) else ( echo 5678 )`
**Output** `1234`

**Execute** `if 11111111111 LSS 22222222222 ( echo 1234 ) else ( echo 5678 )`
**Output** `5678`

**Execute** `if 111111111111 LSS 222222222222 ( echo 1234 ) else ( echo 5678 )`
**Output** `5678`

With 9 Digits or 10 Digits or less, we get Correct Output.
With 11 Digits or 12 Digits or more, we get Wrong Output.

Here , the `If` EXPRESSION fails to Execute & hence it is taken to mean `false`. Hence the `true` Part will not Execute & the `else` Part will Execute.

**Solution :** Avoid calculations & comparison with large numbers. Convert to smaller numbers via **STRING OPERATIONS** & then compare.

Comment: if i use this, "sizemb" is 2047 from a file with 4.587.794.013 bytes.
if i calculate it manualy, the numbers are correct. strange
and i added a /a in the set /a sizemb. without i wont do anything

Comment: I have 1 more alternative, which may work.

Comment: Thanks mate! it works!